# Rails: Calling .limit(5) changes order of results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a search function that basically runs an ordered list of model records. The problem is whenever I called `.search.limit(5)`, the results are in a different order from when I call `.search`

Here is some of my method

```
    def self.search(server_name, pvp_type)
          if server_name.nil?
            result = Rom::Leaderboard.order('pvp_vs desc, win_percent desc').limit(200) 
          end
    end
```

When I call

```
Rom::Leaderboard.search(nil, 2).pluck(:actor_name)
```

SQL Translation:

```
SELECT "rom_leaderboards"."actor_name" FROM "rom_leaderboards" WHERE "rom_leaderboards"."pvp_type" = 2 ORDER BY pvp_vs desc, win_percent desc LIMIT 200
```

I get the following results:

```
[Zarglon, Lirav, adf, sdfa, Nonad, ...]
```

Zarglon and Lirav have the same `pvp_vs` & `win_percent` attribute values; afd, sdfa, and Nonad also have the same relationship.

Now when I call

```
Rom::Leaderboard.search(nil, 2).limit(5).pluck(:actor_name)
```

SQL Translation:

```
SELECT "rom_leaderboards"."actor_name" FROM "rom_leaderboards" WHERE "rom_leaderboards"."pvp_type" = 2 ORDER BY pvp_vs desc, win_percent desc LIMIT 5
```

I get the following results:

```
[Lirav, Zarglon, sfda, Nonad, adf]
```

These queries are both correct (since search returns a ordered list based on `pvp_vs & win_percent` and both list are ordered correctly). But I want them to be the same. For some reason limit changes this order. Is there anyway to keep them the same?

Comment: Please post the respective SQL queries from the logs for each variation.

Comment: Just FYI, your code could be rewritten to be **much** cleaner and more idiomatic: http://codepad.org/TnzCtgMA

Comment: @meagar Yep, and if you take the limit as an option, defaulting to 200, it would immediately solve the OP's problem.

Comment: are you using postgres?

Comment: Yes I am using postgres

Comment: You need to understand databases in general. Basically if you ask for certain columns to be ordered, you are only guaranteed to get rows sorted by those columns. You should *expect* randomness when the values of the ordered columns match. You only get what you asked for. If you have other ordering criteria, you need to include those also. An amorphous criterion like "give me the order you previously gave me" is not something you can ask a database for.

Comment: Why is #search a class method and not a scope?

Comment: @farnoy: Class methods are scopes and ["Using a class method is the preferred way to accept arguments for scopes."](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments).

Comment: But they cant stack then, right? `Leaderboard.where('whatever = 3').search(nil, 2)`

Comment: @farnoy: You might want to read that link in my comment.

Comment: @meagar: Are you sure about starting with `scope = Rom::Loaderboard`?

Comment: @muistooshort Ah, good catch, fixed; http://codepad.org/LyCGQG5S

Comment: I only see "Using a class method is the preferred way to accept arguments for scopes. These methods will still be accessible on the association objects". Association proxies and AR::Relation are different, so still unsure if they stack

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you try to order this array-of-arrays by the first element:

```
[
  [ 1, 1 ],
  [ 1, 2 ],
  [ 1, 3 ]
]
```

Both of these (and several others) are valid results because you have duplicate sort keys:

```
[ [1,1], [1,2], [1,3] ]
[ [1,3], [1,1], [1,2] ]
```

You're encountering the same problem inside the database. You say that:

> Zarglon and Lirav have the same `pvp_vs` & `win_percent` attribute values; afd, sdfa, and Nonad also have the same relationship.

So those five values can appear in any order and still satisfy your specified ORDER BY condition. They don't even have to come out of the database in the same order in two executions of the same query.

If you want consistent ordering, you need to ensure that each row in your result set has a unique sort key so that ties will be broken consistently. This is ActiveRecord so you'll have a unique `id` available so you can use that to break your ordering ties:

```
result = Rom::Leaderboard.order('pvp_vs desc, win_percent desc, id').limit(200) 
# --------------------------------------------------------------^^
```

That will give you a well defined and unique ordering.